# Laravel: Reverse WHERE NOT IN - exclude any parent table that has children of id=XXX

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

**Scenario is this**: Need to get all sites which don't have licensee `ID = XXX`.

```
  $data = DB::select("SELECT  * FROM sites AS s
              WHERE status = 'Existing Site' AND
              $sharerId NOT IN (SELECT organisation_id
                      FROM licensees AS l
                        WHERE site_id = s.id)
                    order by siteName;") ;
```

This code does that fine.

But I get an array, which I can't filter on later using `::where(..)`, just in case the user wants to search for site name `YYY`. I've got a generic model method that handles all types of searches and sorts, I don't want to duplicate the code just for this.

`$sharerId` has the ID to exclude from the sites.

```
     $data = $this->select($select)
     ->where('status', 'Existing Site')
     ->whereNotIn($sharerId,
     Licensee::select('organisation_id')
     ->where('site_id', DB::raw('sites.id'))
     )->get() ;
```

Tried this, but I really didn't expect it to work, and it didn't :-P

Comment: From what you've said, this looks like a pretty straightforward query on the relationships.  Any reason why you're not using a relation query instead of that SQL?  Laravel is really good in this space - if you don't have the relationships set up, you may wish to add them, as it would perhaps make your life a lot easier.  If you do have them, please post them.

Comment: @Watercayman can you expand on that? I've picked up Laravel in bits and pieces. I did get the code working above by wrapping `DB::raw($sharerId)`. But I would be interested to know more about what you're referring to.

Comment: With a defined relationship, Laravel can provide a simple secondary database pull with an eager load, and with this, you can sub-query or pull whereNotIn directly as needed.  You might have sites, sharer, and organisation models and then pull the pre-defined relations with a simple query that gives you both primary and related models... simply.  Sorry - probably much more clear in the docs than me trying to explain in a comment:  https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1):

My crazy idea did work in the end:

```
 $data = $this->select($select)
 ->where('status', 'Existing Site')
 ->whereNotIn(DB::raw($sharerId),
 Licensee::select('organisation_id')
 ->where('site_id', DB::raw('sites.id'))) ;
```

All I needed was `DB::raw($sharerId)`